# Hadoop datanode not connecting to self, cannot edit /etc/hosts

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm setting up a 2-node Hadoop cluster on Ubuntu.
Starting the DFS and Yarn seems to work fine, no problems in the logs and all required processes are running.
To get to this part however, I had to replace all occurrences of *master* and *slave* in the configuration files with the respective IP addresses, to solve some connectivity issues.

I tought these issues were solved, but when I now run my code most tasks fail. The *syslog* files in the user logs show the following message:

> 2015-03-31 09:02:26,660 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client:
>   Retrying connect to server:
>   slavename.host.be./127.0.1.1:57654. Already tried 6
>   time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000
>   MILLISECONDS)

According to https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused a common problem on Ubuntu is entries for the hostname mapping to 127.0.1.1  in /etc/hosts. This is the case in my installation, but I can't change it because I don't have root access.
I have tried editing ~/hosts, without success.

How can I fix this issue, and work around not having root access to edit /etc/hosts here?

Thanks!

I'm using the following versions:
Hadoop  2.6.0
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score -1):

Type this in terminal:

```
sudo bash
```

or

```
sudo su -
```

It will ask for current user password. Enter your current user password. If successful, you will enter into root login in terminal.

Now type, `nano /etc/hosts` and do necessary modifications. Press `Ctrl+X` to exit and press `Y` to save before exit.

Note: In /etc/hosts file, comment the line with `127.0.1.1`.

In case, you haven't enabled root user by default, type this in terminal to enable root user:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Now, enter your new root password twice. You can now login as root using this password.

Comment: I guess the question was not how to get root, but rather what to do if one cannot get root...